# Excel Nested IF AND

Tags: excel

I have the following formula:

```
=IF(AND(A1=0,A3="","1 item"),
    IF(AND(A1=0,A3="Exclude","1  item"),
       IF(AND(A1=1,A3="Exclude","1 item","2 items"))))
```

3 combinations of cell values in A1 and A3 return text which I'm calling "1 item"
Only 1 combination of cells value returns text which I'm calling "2 items".
The only combination to return "2 items" is where `A1=1 AND A3=""`.
The formatting is wrong but I'm not sure where.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can give some sample data and expected output for us to help

Answer (score 1):

Excel's IF expects three parameters: Condition, What to do if condition is TRUE, and what to do if condition is FALSE.

I'll re-format your formula so you can see where the error is:

```
IF( AND(A1=0,A3="","1 item") ,
    IF(AND(A1=0,A3="Exclude","1 item"),
       IF(AND(A1=1,A3="Exclude","1 item","2 items")
         )
      )
  )
```

As you can see

- For the first IF you are not providing what to do if condition is FALSE,
- The same for the second IF,
- The third IF has no definition of what to do if the condition is TRUE or FALSE.

Hope this helps you.

**UPDATE**

Following your comment (which is still not clear to me), hereinafter I'm providing simple rules you may use to construct your formula correctly:

1. Write your formula as a piece of text (like the example I show above) so that you can easily read, edit and verify it,
2. Remember that Excel's IF has three parameters: Condition, result when condition is TRUE and result when condition is FALSE,
3. Within any of these three parameters, you can include whatever you want **PROVIDED** that the result is compliant with what the function expects for that parameter; for instance, writing for the first parameter `3=8` is completely legal since the result is FALSE (while `4=2*2` would yield TRUE).

Having this in mind, here is the formula I think you are looking for (WARNING!!! I'm not sure I understood what you need, but if not, changing it should be very easy for you now):

```
IF(AND(A1=1,A3=""),"2 items","1 item")
```

This is based on your wording: *The only combination to return "2 items" is where A1=1 AND A3=""*.

Comment: Hi FDavidov, thanks for the reply. What I'd like the logic to do is to check the the first 3 conditions. If each is true in turn then it returns "1 item" if it is false it checks the next condition and so on until the final condition is checked returned as either "1 item" or "2 items".

Answer (score 1):

this is the correct formula -

brackets of AND() were not properly closed.

```
=IF(AND(A1=0,A3=""),"1 item",IF(AND(A1=0,A3="Exclude"),"1 item",IF(AND(A1=1,A3="Exclude"),"1 item","2 items")))
```

Comment: Thanks Praveen. This is how i want the logic to work: Cell A1=1 and A3="Exclude": Result="1 item", Cell A1=0 and A3="": Result="1 item", Cell A1=0 and A3="Exclude": Result="1 item", Cell A1=1 and A3="": Result = "2 items". Hope this helps.

Comment: @PeteM for your case, try this formula -
    =IF(AND(A1=1,A3=""),"2 items",IF(OR(AND(A1=1,A3="Exclude"),AND(A1&""="0",A3=""),AND(A1&""="0",A3="Exclude")),"1 item",""))
If works, please mark my answer. thanks :)